# Java Socket PrintWriter Works Once Only?

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

Hello i am trying to make a chat that use sockets and when i am trying to send data to the client it sends it once but then its not receiving anything then i noticed that its printwriter messed up i tried other ways but it does the same it only works once even i tried to copy everything from a tutorial online it does the SAME! does not work like it should soo whats the problem here? the printwriter should be able to send data more than once. I am developing this in JavaFX.

This is the printwriter function code that execute on button press:

```
public void testfunction(ActionEvent event){
            //new Thread(new ListenerThread()).start();
            //play();
            //ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Hello, hello?");
            //TabPaneTabSlavesSlavesList.setItems(list);
                /*System.out.println("Pc index: " + connectedClients.get(0).getLocalAddress().getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
                System.out.println("Pc index: " + connectedClients.get(0).getLocalAddress().getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName());
                System.out.println("Pc index: " + connectedClients.get(0).getLocalAddress().getLocalHost().getAddress());
                System.out.println("Pc index: " + connectedClients.get(0).getLocalAddress().getLocalHost().getHostName());*/

                // Neina gauti ip ar kanors tokio su sitom funkcijomis FIX: Paimti informatcija ir persiusti su stream.

            try {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int myrand = rand.nextInt(50) +1;
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connectedClients.get(0).getOutputStream());
                pw.println("PINGiamconnected: " + Integer.toString(myrand));
                pw.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

This is the listener code that is working on a thread:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = MainController.serverSocket.accept();
            MainController.connectedClients.add(clientSocket);
            MainController.NewClientConnected = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And here is the reader on the client that is also working on a thread:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MainController.socket.getInputStream()));
            //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(MainController.socket.getInputStream());
            String line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I think thats all you guys need i think if you need something more tell me. Thanks.

Comment: So many things wrong with this, that you've obviously not followed a proper networking tutorial. I recommend you go find one now (I recommend the Oracle tutorials), to avoid further frustration when things won't work the way you expect.

Comment: Do you know a video tutorial? i dont like reading. I know programming i can create anything even games but networking is new to me.

Comment: If you don't like reading, programming is probably not the best choice for you.

Comment: I have created a lot of giant projects soo programming is not a problem i just dont like tutorials that i need to read.

Comment: Oh I'm sure you have.

Comment: It's really irrelevant to me. I can only imagine it being extremely difficult to get a broad knowledge of something as complex as software development, if you can only use videos as learning material. Not to mention the whole issue of reading code.

Comment: I fixed it the problem was that the thread executed only 1 time and then stopped it did work all that time

Comment: Did you also fix the design issues (such as using `connectedClients.get(0).getOutputStream()` repeatedly, when you should be getting it only once)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it the problem was that the thread executed only 1 time and then stopped it did work all that time – GrimReaper